# Chrome - 06.2022 - Opening multiple tabs at once - how to stop them from loading immediate? I'd rather have them idle until viewed

Tags: google-chrome

**My workspace:**
I mainly use OneTab in Chrome. Extension that saves Browsing sessions in lists of URLs.
Restarting a specific browsing session I'll open about 35 Tabs and resume my work.

**Why this is a problem:**
I have one website for example that blocks my IP adress as soon as I open (request) >15 URLS at once.
So instead of bulk opening them from my list I have to wait 10sec. after every URL

**What I want:**
There used to be a way to only load new tabs when they were viewed. Imagine typing the URL in the bar but not hitting enter. Viewing the tab would hit enter and load the page.

Any suggestions?
I can't remember if this was an extension or build in feature.